# Trying to Commentate using gaming headsets (TRSS connections)

Tags: amplifiers

My goal is to have 4 headsets (with mics) commentate at softball games over livestream.  We currently are able to use a splitter and have 2 headsets running, but am looking to jump to 4.  We are successfully connecting the headsets using a type C to 1/8" headphone TRSS connector to Samsung S21 Ultra currently.  The livestream app uses the MEVO camera and runs through the phone.  To get to 4 headsets and still be able to connect to phone, what headphone amplifier set up would be the most economic.  I see several "headphone amplifiers no AMAZON for $20-60, but they say for TRS connections.  Would that work if I had a TRS  -> TRSS adapter, or what would be best?

TIA,
Jarad

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would better suit on sound.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's not suitable for Sound Design either, it's a shopping request. https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ would be the only stack it's on topic for, but it's going to require quite a long answer to disabuse the OP of their misconceptions before heading towards an actual product recommendation.